# Why do I get a MemoryError with itertools.product?

Tags: python, python-itertools

I would expect the following snippet to give me an iterator yielding pairs from the Cartesian product of the two input iterables:

```
$ python
Python 2.7.1+ (r271:86832, Apr 11 2011, 18:13:53) 
[GCC 4.5.2] on linux2
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import itertools
>>> one = xrange(0, 10**9)
>>> two = (1,)
>>> prods = itertools.product(one, two)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
MemoryError
```

Instead, I get a `MemoryError`. But I thought that [`itertools.product`](http://docs.python.org/library/itertools.html#itertools.product) did not store the intermediate results in memory, so what's causing the `MemoryError`?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

It doesn't store intermediate *results*, but it has to store the input values because each of those might be needed several times for several output values.

Since you can only iterate once over an iterator, `product` cannot be implemented equivalent to this:

```
def prod(a, b):
  for x in a:
    for y in b:
       yield (x, y)
```

If here `b` is an iterator, it will be exhausted after the first iteration of the outer loop and no more elements will be produced in subsequent executions of `for y in b`.

`product` works around this problem by storing all the elements that are produced by `b`, so that they can be used repeatedly:

```
def prod(a, b):
  b_ = tuple(b)  # create tuple with all the elements produced by b
  for x in a:
    for y in b_:
       yield (x, y)
```

In fact, `product` tries to store the elements produced by all the iterables it is given, even though that could be avoided for its first parameter. The function only needs to walk over the first iterable once, so it wouldn't have to cache those values. But it tries to do anyway, which leads to the `MemoryError` you see.

Comment: Thanks for filling out the motivation of the implementation. I suppose the only other way to get around this would be to insist that the supplied iterables are somehow copyable as well.

Comment: I got the source of the problem. But what is a workaround if one does need functionality of product() ?

Comment: @DSR Did you ever find one?

Answer (score 7):

`itertools.product` does not store the intermediate products in memory, but it does store `tuple` versions of the original iterators.

This can be seen by looking at the source of the `itertools` module. It's in the file `Modules/itertoolsmodule.c` in the Python 2.7.2 source distribution. There we find, in the function `product_new` (basically the constructor for the `product` object) from line 1828 onwards:

```
for (i=0; i < nargs ; ++i) {
    PyObject *item = PyTuple_GET_ITEM(args, i);
    PyObject *pool = PySequence_Tuple(item);
    if (pool == NULL)
        goto error;
    PyTuple_SET_ITEM(pools, i, pool);
    indices[i] = 0;
}
```

In that code, `args` are the arguments to `product`. In the third line of this code piece, the `i`th argument is converted to a tuple. Hence, the code tries to convert your iterator `xrange(0, 10**9)` to a tuple, resulting in a `MemoryError`.

I am not sure why `itertools.product` behaves like this. Instead of storing each input iterator as a tuple it should be enough to store the last item returned from each iterator. *(EDIT: See sth's answer for the reason)*

Comment: That's quite interesting. I suppose for something this simple I could just construct my own generator though.

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem could be that xrange returns its own special sort of object, which is not a normal iterable.

xrange is implemented in such a way (as are lists) that you can iterate over the object many times,
while you can iterate over a normal generator object only once. So perhaps something from this functionality is responsible for the memory error.