# Python's itertools product memory consumption

Tags: python, generator, python-itertools

The [documentation](http://docs.python.org/library/itertools.html#itertools.product) says that the cartesian product function

```
the actual implementation does not build up intermediate results in memory.
```

How can that be possible with generators? Can somebody show me an example
with a bounded memory consumption for 2 generators?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Why do I get a MemoryError with itertools.product?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/8695422/222914)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Looking at the module's source code, `itertools.product()` actually converts every argument to a tuple:

```
// product_new() in itertoolsmodule.c
for (i=0; i < nargs ; ++i) {
    PyObject *item = PyTuple_GET_ITEM(args, i);
    PyObject *pool = PySequence_Tuple(item); //<==== Call tuple(arg)
    if (pool == NULL)
        goto error;
    PyTuple_SET_ITEM(pools, i, pool);
    indices[i] = 0;
}
```

In other words, `itertools.product()`'s memory consumption appears to be linear in the size of the input arguments.

Answer (score 4):

Well, it also says:

> The nested loops cycle like an odometer with the rightmost element
>   advancing on every iteration. This pattern creates a lexicographic
>   ordering so that if the input’s iterables are sorted, the product
>   tuples are emitted in sorted order.

This is pretty much how it works in the implementation (`Modules/itertoolsmodule.c`)

Here is the state object:

```
typedef struct {
    PyObject_HEAD
    PyObject *pools;       /* tuple of pool tuples */
    Py_ssize_t *indices;   /* one index per pool */
    PyObject *result;      /* most recently returned result tuple */
    int stopped;           /* set to 1 when the product iterator is exhausted */
} productobject;
```

And the next item is returned by the function `product_next`, which uses this state and the algorithm described in the quote to generate the next state. See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8695700/8206) to understand the memory requirements.

For general education, you can read about how to create generators with state from C extensions [here](http://eli.thegreenplace.net/2012/04/05/implementing-a-generatoryield-in-a-python-c-extension/).