# Multiple for-loops break in Python

Tags: python, for-loop, break

I'am solving Euler's project and right now triyn to solve 9 task.

The solution I've found is in 3 nested loops:

```
for ai in range(1, 100):
   for bi in range(1, 100):
      for ci in range(1,100):
          if ai + bi + ci == 25 and ai * ai = ci:
             break
```

but when last if find the solution for-loops continues and I wanna break all of them. 
**Is it posible?** I thougt about using some flags but it's additional check for each step and makes execution longer.

Comment: What is `Euler`s project` please explain it in the question as well!

Comment: Put the loops in a function and return the answer instead of breaking.

Comment: if you need `ai + bi + ci == 25` then for `ai = 1` you have to check `bi` only in range `1..24` or even in `1..23` because `ci` has to be at least `1`.

Comment: if you have `ai + bi + ci == 25` then `ci == 25 - ai - b1` and you can use it with second part `ai * ai ==  25 - ai - b1` so you will have one variable less and one loop less.

Comment: @DeveshKumarSingh, Euler project is a list of math tasks with growning up level of difficulty. You can find it here: https://projecteuler.net/archives

Comment: just for the record. break only breaks the current loop. and you already get an answer by using exceptions and raising one. another solution is to use a function then return the result, another one is to use an indicator , if the if is reached then a variable of type bool may take true (exitLoop = true) and test it for each loop and use break for each one ( too much code to write but nothins special)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### You could either

- Put it in a function and return the value as soon as it is reached

or

- Raise an exception once the value is reached, and pass:

```py
try:
    for ai in range(1, 100):
       for bi in range(1, 100):
          for ci in range(1, 100):
              if ai + bi + ci == 25 and ai * ai = ci:
                 raise BreakE
except BreakE:
    pass
```

Comment: I also thought about exit() but its not good when you need the code to be executed, so the return is better solution, I think.
 Thank you!

Comment: This is a bad design to raise an exception to not do anything with it later, which is what is done here

Answer (score 6):

Because your `range()` sequences are *fixed*, you don't need to use nested `for` loops. Instead, use a single loop over [`itertools.product()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.product):

```
from itertools import product

for ai, bi, ci in product(range(1, 100), repeat=3):
    if ai + bi + ci == 25 and ai * ai == ci:
         break
```

Next, remove one of the repeats and lower the range values; you can trivially *calculate* `ci` from `ai` and `bi`, and ranging beyond 23 is pointless (as `ci` will only be 1 or greater if `ai + bi` is 24 or less):

```
for ai, bi in product(range(1, 23), repeat=2):
    ci = 25 - ai - bi
    if ai * ai == ci:
         break
```

That `ci` can be negative here doesn't matter, as `ai * ai` will always be a positive number.

Note that the above equation has *four solutions*, so breaking out on the first may not be the correct answer. You can calculate all possible solutions for a given target value with:

```
def triplets(target):
    return (
        (ai, bi, target - ai - bi)
        for ai, bi in product(range(1, target - 2), repeat=2)
        if ai * ai == target - ai - bi
    )
```

This returns a generator, so can be asked for a single solution at a time with [`next()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#next):

```
gen = triplets(25)
print(next(gen, None))
```

If your inner loop sequences are dependent on the value of a parent loop, and you can't simplify the loop (like the `ci = 25 - ai - bi` assignment above), then you *perhaps* need to use nested loops. You can always break out of such structures with an exception you catch; even standard `ValueError` would do, or create a custom exception:

```
class Break(Exception):
    pass

try:
    for ai in <some_sequence>:
        for bi in range(<based on ai>):
            if <condition>:
                raise Break
except Break:
    # nested set of loops has exited
```

or nest the loop in a function and use `return`:

```
def nested_loops(<arguments>):
    for ai in <some_sequence>:
        for bi in range(<based on ai>):
            if <condition>:
                return ai, bi
```

Comment: What if I need this loops should be different length? 
For example, ai from 1 to bi and c from 1 to 1000.

Comment: @ЕвгенийКрючков: if inner loops depend on outer values, then you have to use nesting. You can raise exceptions or nest the loop in a function with `return`.

Comment: And remember kids... if N is wasn't small enough the good old itertools.product could give you a nice MemoryError [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8695422/why-do-i-get-a-memoryerror-with-itertools-product](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8695422/why-do-i-get-a-memoryerror-with-itertools-product) ;)

Comment: @BPL: yup, `itertools.product()` materialises all sequences passed to it into tuples.